# Vim using shell, how can I stop job like C-z in Unix?

Tags: vim, shell, unix

I have a quick question about programming using Vim. I sometimes make a silly mistake in my program.

For example, the Python code below has an infinite loop (say `foo.py` . . . be careful when executing it!)

```
x = 1
while x == 1:
    x = 1
```

You won't see any result, but find a fan inside your computer is becoming louder, and you need to stop executing this Python program. On a Unix shell, you can do it by pressing `Ctrl-z`. Or, on Emacs shell-mode, just pressing `Ctrl-c Ctrl-z`.

I know how to switch to shell-mode in Vim: `:sh` (then type `python foo.py`) or `:!python foo.py`. But I don't know **how to stop a job on a shell from Vim without killing Vim itself**. Does anyone know this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why can't you use <kbd><C-C></kbd>? By default, it sends an INTerrupt signal unless program is able to catch <kbd><C-C></kbd>. Vim handles <kbd><C-C></kbd> like any other <kbd><C-...></kbd> key, but python does not do this by default.

By the way, <kbd><C-Z></kbd> in unix shells suspends program while in the case mentioned above you need to kill it which is done using <kbd><C-C></kbd>. Suspend=pause executing (though most programs are not able to/do not need to handle SIGTSTP/SIGCONT properly).

Comment: Also thank you for teaching us essential stuff of Unix command usage--It's a shame that I didn't know that!

Answer (score 0):

```
pkill <process name>
```

or

`ps -ef`, find the process then `kill -9 <process id>` (this is safer)

Comment: You meant, from another terminal emulator? When a certain job is running on a shell on Vim, it seems impossible to put any Unix command except for `Ctrl-z` which kills Vim as well.

Answer (score 0):

How do you determine that vim is "killed"? The `:sh` command starts a shell which looks like your normal shell. When the shell exits (e.g. after <kbd>Ctrl-D</kbd>) you return to Vim.

Comment: For example, when you write the code above on Vim and switch to a shell by pressing `:sh`, and execute it like `python foo.py`, and you want to suspend the python program and return to the shell or Vim, without killing Vim itself (i.e. not `Ctrl-D`.)